# How to open Start Menu with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I want a .vbs file that opens the Start Menu.

Can someone give me a code that opens Start Menu, that works with Windows 8.1/10?

Comment: You should at least show what did have tried as code before, or you will downvoted by the membres here !
Try my answer below. and i don't know why some people make some downvote randomly without testing even the code works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that : a vbsript for opening the Start Menu

```
Dim WSHShell
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "^{ESC}"
Set WSHShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit(0)
```