# Open startmenu from file

Tags: shortcut, windows-scripting, startmenu

I'd like to open the start menu with winXcorners by calling a custom shortcut (to bat, vbs, ps, exe that calls one of those, I don't care) and did not find anything online.

Somehow Autohotkey can open the start menu, so I think in the worst case I have to write something in there, call it from a batch file which I call from winXcorners. However, do you know a solution that would not require an additional programs?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803544/how-to-open-start-menu-with-vbscript) but it didn't work.

Regards, Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the one-liner ahk script that will open the start menu for you. It is based off of the Windows shortcut Control+Escape, which opens up the mentioned menu.

```
SendInput ^{esc}
```

If all you want the hotcorner to do is open up the start menu, you can just have winXcorners execute the script directly, without using any batch scripts. Otherwise, if you need to run it inside a batch script, with something like

```
start C:\folder\myAhkScript.ahk
```

replacing the `C:\folder\myAhkScript.ahk` directory with wherever you saved the script on your computer.